# I want to print 1 to11,2 to 22 etc with N parallel processes

Tags: printing, process, system

```
shared var K = L = 1;
    Process_i
while (TRUE) { 
L:=K; 
K:=K+11;
print_num(L, L+10);
}
```

- Explanation:

`print_num` is a routine to print numbers from `L` to `L+10`.

I want to accomplish the following scenario:

- 1st time prints from 1 to 11
- 2nd time from 12 to 22
- 3rd from 23 to 33 etc.

The question states that the parallel execution of this can lead to unwanted  results(ask us to provide a scenario that leads to them)  and to fix this problem using  semaphores(up/down).
Has anyone got any clue? Because I'm a bit stuck on this

Comment: What language is this?  You need to provide more information.

Comment: This is C, course is Operating Systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `print_num()` executes in a new thread, each call to it is subject to race conditions.  For example `print_num(12,22)` could end up executing before `print_num(1,11)` and the output would be out of order.  Or, two or more executions could be printing to STDOUT simultaneously resulting in jumbled output.

You use a semaphore to control access to a limited resource, in this case STDOUT.  You can also use a lock.  Basically you need to add some code to prevent `print_num` from executing out of called order and only one instance of it can access STDOUT at a time.  You should also add code to the `while` loop so that it doesn't iterate until `print_num` is up and running and has established its place in the execution order.

HTH